# format currency textbox in asp?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have one textbox to enter the currency in SQL. I used SQL server format is money when I import it into SQL 400000 400000.00 and I found that when I used this column to bring up your data on a textbox to revise it again on textbox is 400000.0000. And now I want to reformat the textbox is 400,000 and they are put to such formats SQL also dc not? Can anyone help me with

Comment: Please tag your DBMS and its version.

Comment: I did not understand you very well

Comment: Your database management system, are you using sql server ? , mysql ? etc.. also kindly include it's version

Comment: Store your money as unformatted numbers.  Do your formatting in c#.

Comment: use String.Format to format decimals with thousand separator. Please keep in mind that you have to format it back to decimal when update database.